# Suspect code running twice or not at all sometimes, intermittent issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The code below is causing me some real headaches.  It was written probably two years ago and has been chugging away ever since, but we've noticed that sometimes the insert query will run twice, and sometimes not at all.  The code basically takes integer and decimal values from webpage (aspx) labels and inserts them into a master table.

The problem lately seems to be affected by the number of users on the system.  When there is only one person using it there seems to be no issue, but with multiple users the problems start to occur.  I was using session variables rather than labels but as a process of elimination i stopped using these.

If anyone can help or give me some pointers that would be great, many thanks.

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    'local
    Dim subidString As String = "SELECT [Submission_ID], [Week Ending] FROM tbl_Weekly_Expenses WHERE [Submission_ID] = @SubID AND [Week Ending] = @WeekEnding AND [SentToPayroll] IS NULL"

    'local
    Dim mtdString As String = "SELECT SUM([Mileage Covered]) AS SumOfMileageCovered FROM tbl_Weekly_Expenses WHERE [Gabem Employee Reference] = @NovaRef"

    'remote
    Dim vehicleString As String = "SELECT [Vehicle] FROM tblExpensesMileage WHERE [SubID] = @SubID"

    'local
    Dim insertString As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_Weekly_Expenses ([Week Ending], [Date Expenses Processed], [Expenses_From], [Expenses_To], [Date Expenses received], [Gabem Employee Reference], [Identifying Number], [Submission_ID], [Car], [Motorcycle], [Pushbike], [Mileage Covered], [Mileage Amount Claimed], [Accommodation], [Meal Allowance], [Daily Allowance], [Tools/Clothing], [Details_Of_Tools], [Travel Amount], [Telephone], [Professional Fees], FuelVAT, MAVAT, TAVAT, AVAT, DAVAT, TCVAT, TelVAT, PfVAT, processedby) " & _
                                 "VALUES (@WeekEnding, @DateProcessed, @ExpensesFrom, @ExpensesTo, @DateReceived, @NovaRef, @IdentifyingNumber, @SubID, @Car, @Motorcycle, @Pushbike, @MileageCovered, @MileageAmountClaimed, @Accommodation, @Meals, @DailyAllowance, @ToolsClothing, @ToolsDetails, @Travel, @TelephoneCalls, @ProfessionalFees, @FuelVAT, @MAVAT, @TAVAT, @AVAT, @DAVAT, @TCVAT, @TelVAT, @PfVAT, @processedby)"

    'remote
    Dim updateMileage As String = "UPDATE tblExpensesMileage SET [Status] = 'Processed' WHERE [MileageID] = @id"
    Dim updateAccommodation As String = "UPDATE tblExpensesAccommodation SET [Status] = 'Processed' WHERE [AccommodationID] = @id"
    Dim updateMeals As String = "UPDATE tblExpensesMeals SET [Status] = 'Processed' WHERE [MealsID] = @id"
    Dim updateLaundry As String = "UPDATE tblExpensesLaundry SET [Status] = 'Processed' WHERE [LaundryID] = @id"
    Dim updateDailyAllowance As String = "UPDATE tblExpensesDailyAllowance SET [Status] = 'Processed' WHERE [DailyAllowanceID] = @id"
    Dim updateTravel As String = "UPDATE tblExpensesTravel SET [Status] = 'Processed' WHERE [TravelID] = @id"
    Dim updateTools As String = "UPDATE tblExpensesTools SET [Status] = 'Processed' WHERE [ToolsID] = @id"
    Dim updateTelephoneCalls As String = "UPDATE tblExpensesTelephoneCalls SET [Status] = 'Processed' WHERE [TelephoneCallsID] = @id"
    Dim updateProfessionalFees As String = "UPDATE tblExpensesProfessionalFees SET [Status] = 'Processed' WHERE [ProfessionalFeesID] = @id"

    Dim dbconnLocal As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connection_nbsas2").ConnectionString
    Dim dbconnRemote As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connection_nbsa_web").ConnectionString

    If txtWEDate.Text = String.Empty Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Using myConnectionLocal As New SqlConnection(dbconnLocal)
        myConnectionLocal.Open()

        'VEHICLE TYPE AND PPM STARTS
        Dim Car As Integer = 0
        Dim Motorcycle As Integer = 0
        Dim Pushbike As Integer = 0
        Dim ppm As Decimal
        Using myConnectionRemote As New SqlConnection(dbconnRemote)
            myConnectionRemote.Open()

            'Vehicle type
            Dim cmdSelectVehicle As New SqlCommand(vehicleString, myConnectionRemote)
            cmdSelectVehicle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubID", Session("subid"))
            Dim readerVehicle As SqlDataReader = cmdSelectVehicle.ExecuteReader()
            readerVehicle.Read()
            If readerVehicle.HasRows = True Then
                'MTD value for pence per mile (ppm)
                Dim cmdSelectMTD As New SqlCommand(mtdString, myConnectionLocal)
                cmdSelectMTD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NovaRef", Session("novaref"))
                Dim readerMTD As SqlDataReader = cmdSelectMTD.ExecuteReader()
                readerMTD.Read()
                If IsDBNull(readerMTD.Item(0)) = True Then
                    If readerVehicle.Item(0) = "Car" Then
                        ppm = 0.45
                        Car = "1"
                    ElseIf readerVehicle.Item(0) = "Motorcycle" Then
                        ppm = 0.24
                        Motorcycle = "1"
                    Else
                        ppm = 0.2
                        Pushbike = "1"
                    End If
                Else
                    If readerVehicle.Item(0) = "Motorcycle" Then
                        ppm = 0.24
                        Motorcycle = "1"
                    ElseIf readerVehicle.Item(0) = "Car" And readerMTD.Item(0) < 10000 Then
                        ppm = 0.45
                        Car = "1"
                    ElseIf readerVehicle.Item(0) = "Car" And readerMTD.Item(0) > 10000 Then
                        ppm = 0.25
                        Car = "1"
                    Else
                        ppm = 0.2
                        Pushbike = "1"
                    End If
                End If
                readerMTD.Close()
            End If
            readerVehicle.Close()
            myConnectionRemote.Close()
        End Using
        'VEHICLE TYPE AND PPM ENDS

        'insert parameters etc
        Dim cmdInsertWE As New SqlCommand(insertString, myConnectionLocal)
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WeekEnding", CType(txtWEDate.Text, DateTime))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateProcessed", Now())
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpensesFrom", CType(lblMinDate.Text, DateTime))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpensesTo", CType(lblMaxDate.Text, DateTime))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateReceived", CType(Session("daterec"), DateTime))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NovaRef", Session("novaref"))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdentifyingNumber", "1")
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubID", Session("subid"))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Car", Car)
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Motorcycle", Motorcycle)
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pushbike", Pushbike)
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MileageCovered", CType(lblMileageNumber.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MileageAmountClaimed", CType(lblMileageNumber.Text, Decimal) * ppm)
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accommodation", CType(lblAccommodationNumber.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Meals", CType(lblMealsNumber.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DailyAllowance", CType(lblDailyAllowanceNumber.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToolsClothing", CType(lblToolsNumber.Text, Decimal) + CType(lblLaundryNumber.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToolsDetails", txtToolsDetails.Text)
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Travel", CType(lblTravelNumber.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelephoneCalls", CType(lblTelephoneCallsNumber.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfessionalFees", CType(lblProfessionalFeesNumber.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FuelVAT", CType(txtRec_Mileage.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MAVAT", CType(txtRec_Meals.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TAVAT", CType(txtRec_Travel.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVAT", CType(txtRec_Accommodation.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DAVAT", CType(txtRec_Daily.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TCVAT", CType(txtRec_ToolsLaundry.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelVAT", CType(txtRec_Telephone.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PfVAT", CType(txtRec_ProFees.Text, Decimal))
        cmdInsertWE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@processedby", Page.User.Identity.Name)

        cmdInsertWE.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmdInsertWE.Dispose()

        myConnectionLocal.Close()

        'also clear totals labels
        lblMileageNumber.Text = 0
        lblAccommodationNumber.Text = 0
        lblMealsNumber.Text = 0
        lblLaundryNumber.Text = 0
        lblDailyAllowanceNumber.Text = 0
        lblTravelNumber.Text = 0
        lblToolsNumber.Text = 0
        txtToolsDetails.Text = String.Empty
        lblTelephoneCallsNumber.Text = 0
        lblProfessionalFeesNumber.Text = 0

    End Using 'myConnectionLocal ENDS

    'OPEN REMOTE CONNECTION AND UPDATE STATUS OF LIVE TABLES
    Using myConnectionRemote As New SqlConnection(dbconnRemote)
        myConnectionRemote.Open()

        'Mileage()
        updateCheckBoxes(MileageGridView, "MileageHeaderCheckBox", "MileageCheckBox", updateMileage, myConnectionRemote, lblMileageNumber)
        'Accommodation()
        updateCheckBoxes(AccommodationGridView, "AccommodationHeaderCheckBox", "AccommodationCheckBox", updateAccommodation, myConnectionRemote, lblAccommodationNumber)
        'Meals()
        updateCheckBoxes(MealsGridView, "MealsHeaderCheckBox", "MealsCheckBox", updateMeals, myConnectionRemote, lblMealsNumber)
        'Laundry()
        updateCheckBoxes(LaundryGridView, "LaundryHeaderCheckBox", "LaundryCheckBox", updateLaundry, myConnectionRemote, lblLaundryNumber)
        'Daily(Allowance)
        updateCheckBoxes(DailyAllowanceGridView, "DailyAllowanceHeaderCheckBox", "DailyAllowanceCheckBox", updateDailyAllowance, myConnectionRemote, lblDailyAllowanceNumber)
        'Travel()
        updateCheckBoxes(TravelGridView, "TravelHeaderCheckBox", "TravelCheckBox", updateTravel, myConnectionRemote, lblTravelNumber)
        'Tools()
        updateCheckBoxes(ToolsGridView, "ToolsHeaderCheckBox", "ToolsCheckBox", updateTools, myConnectionRemote, lblToolsNumber)
        'Telephone(Calls)
        updateCheckBoxes(TelephoneCallsGridView, "TelephoneCallsHeaderCheckBox", "TelephoneCallsCheckBox", updateTelephoneCalls, myConnectionRemote, lblTelephoneCallsNumber)
        'Professional(Fees)
        updateCheckBoxes(ProfessionalFeesGridView, "ProfessionalFeesHeaderCheckBox", "ProfessionalFeesCheckBox", updateProfessionalFees, myConnectionRemote, lblProfessionalFeesNumber)

        myConnectionRemote.Close()
    End Using 'myConnectionRemote ENDS

    txtWEDate.Text = String.Empty

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a lot of code man. Why don't you try cleaning this a little bit? Use some Stored Procedures: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx and some Transactions: http://blog.ashodnakashian.com/2011/11/understanding-ms-sql-transactions-and-error-handling/ and maybe it won't matter how many users are using the app :)

Comment: Likely users who just reload the page. When done use Response.Redirect and they won't be able to reload.

Comment: It's not running on reload. I'll look at SP and transactions, thanks

Comment: The problem here though is that it's running the whole block of code twice - that includes the `cmdInsertWE.ExecuteNonQuery()` statement. I would assume therefore that a rollback wouldn't ever fire.